# How do I create a RSS feed?

Tags: rss

Can you help me with creating an RSS feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any text editor should be able to do it. As for formats/etc, have a look at the Wikipedia entry and links from there:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS

As for code libraries, we can't help you unless you are more specific.

Comment: I can use xHtml and javascript……

Comment: so, can I use these technology creat RSS?

Comment: A server side solution would be better - eg. PHP if you wanted to create a dynamic RSS feed. Or you could create a static one. They're just XML-derived files (as is XHTML).